# JavaScript string eqaulity with & operator

Tags: javascript, operators

```
const returnUrl =
(paymentType === 'order-pay-now' && 'orders/latest') ||
'my-account/overview'
```

What confuses me is the `paymentType === 'order-pay-now' && 'orders/latest'`

Will it first check if `paymentType` equals `order-pay-now` and `orders/latest` will always return true. So writing `paymentType === 'order-pay-now'` achieves the same thing?

I don't see how using `&&` here makes sense. Could this be a bug where `||` should rather have been used?

So `returnUrl` will either be a boolean or a string value of `my-account/overview`??

Comment: @JeremyThille run the code, it actually sets `returnUrl` to `orders/latest`. No clue how though

Comment: @George ah, that's right, my bad

Comment: @JeremyThille It's alright, it got me too, bryan60's answer explains why it does what it do

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this is setting "returnUrl" to 'orders/latest' IF the payment type is 'order-pay-now' else returnUrl is set to 'my-account/overview'

It's taking advantage of the fact that conditional operators return the value of the final condition they need to evaluate in JavaScript rather than just true or false.  TBH, I don't like reading code like this and think people are trying to be too clever when they write this way.

much clearer would've been:

```
const returnUrl = (paymentType === 'order-pay-now') ? 'orders/latest' : 'my-account/overview';
```

there are use cases for using conditionals in this manner though, such as if you're populating an object from a web response with unsure values, and want to set defaults on null values, a good method is to do:

```
myObj.prop = response.prop || 'default value';
```

This way you're saying "set the object property to the response property OR the default" in a clean and readable way.

Answer (score 2):

This is like ternary operator :

```js
var paymentType = `order-pay-now`;

const returnURL = paymentType==='order-pay-now' ? 'orders/latest' :  'my-account/overview'
console.log(returnURL);


const second = ( paymentType==='order-pay-now' && 'orders/latest') ||  'my-account/overview'

console.log(second);
```